# capacitive proximity sensor - how does it work

Tags: circuit-theory

I know 3d printers such as the i3 use a Capacitive proximity sensor to try compensate for the uneven surface of the print bed. for example this one seems to be popular
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00542U3M4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

If am not mistaken a capacitor is formed with two plates and dialetric in this case glass.

Does this sensor work by forming a capacitor between the bed and the sensor i.e. the bed is one plate of the capacitor then the glass is the insulator and then the sensor itself is the other plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the bed is not the second plate.

Those sensors contain both plates of the capacitor, but they are arranged so that the area in front of the sensor is part of the dielectric volume.

If some material is brought into that area, its dielectric constant  and its distance to the sensor changes the capacitance. This allows to detect almost any type of material (your idea would work with conductors only), though calibration is needed to adjust the sensor to the actual material. 
When the object has a large, flat surface, the sensor can be used to measure the exact distance as well.

Comment: ah right it only works with conductors. Explains why I got 12 views and no reply. It was a stupid idea. But it was because I didn't understand the theory I was taught.